# New drag-and-drop mechanism does not work as expected in Qt-Quick (Qt 5.3)

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I've tried to implement drag and drop in Qt 5.3 using the new QML types `Drag`, `DragEvent` and `DropArea`. This is the original example from the [documentation of the QML `Drag` type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-drag.html#details) with some small modifications:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    width: 800; height: 600

    DropArea {
        width: 100; height: 100; anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: parent.containsDrag ? "red" : "green"
        }

        onEntered: print("entered");
        onExited: print("exited");
        onDropped: print("dropped");
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 15; y: 15; width: 30; height: 30; color: "blue"

        Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
        // Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic
        Drag.onDragStarted: print("drag started");
        Drag.onDragFinished: print("drag finished");

        MouseArea {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected behaviour**: The small blue rectangle (drag target) can be dragged around with the mouse. If dragged over the larger green rectangle in the center of the window, this rectangle turns red and back to green when leaving. In addition, the signals *dragStarted*, *entered*, *exited*, *dropped* and *dragFinished* are emitted in time and the corresponding signal handlers print out their messages.

**Experienced behaviour**:

Depends on `Drag.dragType` (see commented line above):

1. `Drag.dragType` is NOT set (default is `Drag.Internal`):

   Drag and drop works as described, but only the signals *entered*  and *exited* are emitted. The other signals (*dragStarted*, *dragFinished* and *dropped*) are suppressed. So there is no way to react to the drop in the `DropArea`.
2. `Drag.dragType` is set to `Drag.Automatic`:

   All of the signals are emitted now, but the blue rectangle (drag target) does not move with the mouse. Instead, the mouse cursor changes its shape to visualize possible drop targets. After the mouse has been released, the blue rectangle jumps to the latest mouse position.

Neither of these two variants are pleasing. How can I get all signals and still be able to drag around the drag target? Unfortunately the documentation is everything but clear about drag-and-drop in QML, especially about the ominous `Drag.dragType`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you open [the `QQuickDrag` source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/fc76abfa52be058ee97b836c2af59cc22f2ca626:src/quick/items/qquickdrag.cpp) and look at the differences between `start()`, which is used by `Drag.Internal`, and `startDrag()` which is used by `Drag.Automatic`, the difference is pretty obvious.  [`start()` sets up an event change listener](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/fc76abfa52be058ee97b836c2af59cc22f2ca626:src/quick/items/qquickdrag.cpp#L552-554), which it then uses to [update the position](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/fc76abfa52be058ee97b836c2af59cc22f2ca626:src/quick/items/qquickdrag.cpp#L239-260) of the attached object.  [`startDrag()` doesn't do this](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/fc76abfa52be058ee97b836c2af59cc22f2ca626:src/quick/items/qquickdrag.cpp#L714-749).

Why does it work this way?  I have no idea!  The QtQuick 2 drag and drop documentation certainly has room for improvement here.

There is a fairly simple workaround: take the best from both worlds.  Use `Drag.Automatic`, but instead of setting `Drag.active`, call `start()` and `drop()` manually.  It won't invoke `Drag.onDragStarted()` and `Drag.onDragFinished()` but you essentially get those for free anyway by listening for a change in the `MouseArea`'s `drag.active`.

Here's the concept in action:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 800; height: 600

    DropArea {
        width: 100; height: 100; anchors.centerIn: parent

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: parent.containsDrag ? "red" : "green"
        }

        onEntered: print("entered");
        onExited: print("exited");
        onDropped: print("dropped");
    }

    Rectangle {
        x: 15; y: 15; width: 30; height: 30; color: "blue"

        // I've added this property for simplicity's sake.
        property bool dragActive: dragArea.drag.active

        // This can be used to get event info for drag starts and 
        // stops instead of onDragStarted/onDragFinished, since
        // those will neer be called if we don't use Drag.active
        onDragActiveChanged: {
            if (dragActive) {
                print("drag started")
                Drag.start();
            } else {
                print("drag finished")
                Drag.drop();
            }
        }

        Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic

        // These are now handled above.
        //Drag.onDragStarted: print("drag started");
        //Drag.onDragFinished: print("drag finished");

        MouseArea {
            id: dragArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }
}
```

I realize it's not a *completely* satisfying solution, but it does match your expected behavior.

This solution offers:

- Notifications for all of the desired events: drag started, drag finished, enter drag area, exit drag area, and dropped in drag area.
- The drag animation is automatically handled by QtQuick.  The square doesn't freeze in place like it does when running the sample code with `Drag.Automatic`.

What it doesn't offer:

- An explanation as to why QtQuick's drag and drop functionality works this way, or whether it's even the intended behavior by the developers.  The current documentation seems ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Although I'm still confused about the different drag types, your solution fullfills my needs as it simulates the required events and hence makes it possible to decouple drag source and drop area. Nevertheless I think that the Qt team should enhance the QtQuick DnD as it is not really useful and intuitive.

Comment: Note that the situation has not changed in Qt 5.15.x, the workaround from this post is still required.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this myself (using Qt 5.2, but the same problem exists there). I've got a 'slider box' on the X-axis and just wanted to know when the drag was finished... instead of responding to every position change along the way. My workaround involved hacking the states/transitions, with a `ScriptAction` to provide the logic. This is the simplified version for mimicking a response to the "onDragFinished" signal. So while it doesn't cover all your drag/drop signals, it might get you pointed in the right direction.

```
Rectangle {
    id: sliderControl

    height: coordinates.height
    width: 80
    color: "#F78181"
    border.color: "#FE2E2E"
    border.width: 1
    opacity: 0.4

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: sliderControl
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
        drag.minimumX: 0
        drag.maximumX: view.width - sliderControl.width
        hoverEnabled: true
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "dragging"
            when: mouseArea.drag.active
        },
        State {
            name: "finished_dragging"
            when: !mouseArea.drag.active
        }
    ]

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "dragging"
            to: "finished_dragging"
            ScriptAction {
                script: console.log("finished dragging script");
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

ps - I know that such a 'workaround' doesn't qualify for the bounty parameters, but I was pretty bummed to find only your question (no solutions) when I searched for help on the issue. Hopefully anyone else stumbling down this path will find this useful. Unfortunately, I've got no clue what's going on with QML's `Drag.dragType` either.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm glad I'm not alone out there! ;) I've also already experimented with some similar solution, but unfortunately in my 'real' code, the drag-initiating `MouseArea` is completely independent from the `DropArea`, which should handle the drop. So communicating the drop event from `MouseArea` to `DropArea` is rather complex / almost impossible without hack. I start thinking that the DnD mechanism in QtQuick is somehow broken...